# Remove password from custom Django User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users

How to remove the password in the users table and User class in a custom user model?

I'm using **django-rest-framework** token authentication, so i don't need the password field.

Here is my model:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(phone, name=None):
        return User.objects.create(
            name=name, phone=phone)

    def create_superuser(name, phone=None):
        pass

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom django User model.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                        null=True, validators=[validate_name])

    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: Are you __sure__ you don't need passwords at all ? Like, say, for having root access to the admin ???

Comment: Yes i'm sure, and I don't want admin access.

Comment: Can we have admin access without password?? Like using OTP or something else?

Comment: Were you able to remove it? How did you remove the password requirement when adding users in admin? I removed password in add_fieldsets but I'm getting `Please correct the errors below.` error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An alternative to removing the password field would be to use [`set_unusable_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password), which marks the user as having no password set.

```py
def create_user(phone, name=None):
    user = User(name=name, phone=phone)
    user.set_unusable_password()
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: This, as it says in the docs .. "You may need this if authentication for your application takes place against an existing external source such as an LDAP directory."

Answer (score 9):

Just override the password attribute:

```
password = None
```