# What is the best way to use phone number and validation code in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to bulid a backend appliaction in django, an i want to have authatication using only phone number, after the client write the phone number he will get a code via sms what is the best way to approch this ?

how can i modify the login and authaticate methods in django base user model

Answer (score 0):

To implement phone number authentication in Django, you can create a Custom User Model, that inherits from AbstractUser like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import UserManager

    class User(AbstractUser):
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
        objects = UserManager()
```

also you need something like this:

https://pypi.org/project/django-phone-verify/

https://github.com/CuriousLearner/django-phone-verify

and this geek for geeks also may help, but with little updates

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/customizing-phone-number-authentication-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to login by doing:

1. User inputs phone number
2. A request for OTP is sent
3. User inputs OTP
4. If match, authenticate user

Seems you need to write a custom user model and a custom authentication backend. Refer to these:

- [Remove password from custom Django User model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922465/remove-password-from-custom-django-user-model)
- [django authentication without a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560182/django-authentication-without-a-password)

For the actual OTP, I recently had to implement it so I'll just share here how I did it. I made a whole app since I will be using it often.

#### `otp/models.py`

```
def generate_otp5():
    random_generator = SystemRandom()
    return random_generator.randint(10000, 99999)

def generate_expiry_10m():
    now = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
    ten_minutes = timedelta(minutes=10)
    return now + ten_minutes

class RegistrationOTP(BasePhoneNumberOTP):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(default=generate_expiry_10m)
    date_used = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    otp = models.IntegerField(default=generate_otp5)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    # from django-phonenumber-field
    
    @property
    def is_expired(self):
    now = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
    return now >= self.date_expired

    @property
    def is_used(self):
        if self.date_used:
            return True
        return False
```

Then, I created a service because I felt this should be one. Place it inside your `models.py` if you want.

#### `otp/services.py`

```
class RegistrationOTPService:
    def __init__(self, phone_number: phonenumber, user_provided_otp: int):
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.user_provided_otp = user_provided_otp

    def resolve(self):
        # Used transaction in case multiple requests are made at the same time.
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:
                latest_record = (
                    RegistrationOTP.objects.select_for_update()
                    .filter(phone_number=self.phone_number)
                    .latest('date_created')
                )
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
                raise InvalidOTPError from e

            if latest_record.is_expired:
                raise InvalidOTPError

            if latest_record.is_used:
                raise InvalidOTPError

            if latest_record.otp != self.user_provided_otp:
                raise InvalidOTPError

            latest_record.date_used = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
            latest_record.save()
```

Lastly, I placed this in my serializer's `validate()`. In your use case, it should be in your authentication backend.

```
    try:
        otp_service = RegistrationOTPService(
            phone_number=data.get('phone_number'),
            user_provided_otp=data.get('otp'),
        )
        otp_service.resolve()
    except InvalidOTPError as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'otp': e}) from e
```